# creating command in yii for mysql

Tags: mysql, yii

How to write or create command as

```
select * from profile where name like r% limit 12,16;
```

in mysql to get the appropriate result in yii.

please any help would be appreciated. thank you in advance

Comment: You are only missing single quotes around `r%`, so it should be `'r%'`. Otherwise I do not see any syntax errors that would prevent you from running the above query in MySQL.

Comment: ok thanks for reply ...okay but i need syntax for statement in yii which is look like above one by createCommand() or CDbCriteria...

Comment: Then why on Earth did not you  say so in the question?

Comment: so sorry As i am new to stackOverflow .I dont know how to use it...sorry

Comment: Sorry, but this is common sense, nothing to do with SO. If you were to ask this question face to face from somebody, even then you would have to tell what you are after, otherwise, you are not going to get any answer. So, pls do not blame this on being new to SO!

Comment: Sorry..sorry.....as i said i dont know how to post question and comment ..leave it sorry again ....

Answer (score 0):

You should use this code:

```
$queryResult = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('select * from profile where name like "r%" limit 12,16;')->queryAll();
```

Result will be an array of associative arrays where keys will represents column names, and values are values fetched from DB.

Comment: I used the following one                                                                         `$data = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('select * from profile where name like "'.$name.'"% limit '.$start.','.$end)->queryAll();`

Comment: `CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '% limit 12,16' at line 1. The SQL statement executed was: select * from profile where name like "j"% limit 12,16 `

Comment: what should I do please help

Comment: You've got syntax error in your SQL: instead of `like "'.$name.'"%` you should have `like "'.$name.'%"`. `%` character is in wrong place :). If it solves problem please mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: thank you...query is right but it doesnot give any output result....as displays no data found

Comment: Maybe there are no results based on that criteria. Try test different params.

Comment: firstly i wanna mention that i am displaying data from table in cgridview along with pagination .and above that i had a search box which display the data started with given character. and the result will be done for all data...rather than pagination...i wanna check whether data started with given character is listed in the particular page in pagination so i have used limit but it doesnt shows any data

Comment: And why you didn't mention it in a question? That is more complicated now. Read about `CArrayDataProvider` with `CGridView`.

Comment: yes ...it is complicated and spend time from yesterday nothing happend..is it possible to get pagination for renderpartial page